# Title и Description не обновляются в Telegram

Tags: html, telegram

Поменял Title и Description на своем сайте. Отправляю ссылку в Telegram, в сообщении прикрепляется Title и Description, но старый. На самом сайте он обновился.
В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Подождите немного, обновится

Comment: Я часов 12 назад обновил. Долго ждать?

Answer (score 1):

Телеграм кеширует эти данные. Для обновления кеша используйте телеграм-бота

@WebpageBot